# Prevent form to submit if click enter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have this simple form

```
<form action="http://localhost/my_project/account_control" id="generate" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="personnel">Personnel Password</label>
    <input class="form-control panel__input-container" name="personnel" type="password" placeholder="password" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="authority__button-container center-block">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default button--dark" id="reset-save"><span><i class="fa fa-save"></i></span> SAVE</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

My program, is using **ajax** to submit data in the given form attribute `action="http://localhost/my_project/account_control"`when the logged-in user clicked on the button.

Here's the ajax.

```
$('#reset-save').click(function() {
  url     = $(this).parents('form').attr('action') + '/reset_user_password';
  form_id = $(this).parents('form').attr('id');

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $('#'+form_id).serialize(),
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success:(result) => { // My Message Here },
    error: function(result) { // My error message here },
    beforeSend: function() { },
    completes: function() { }
  }); // end of ajax

});
```

The problem is, if the user is too fast on typing password and suddenly hit `enter` on the keyboard, the form trigger the submit and cause error on the page.

How can I disable that?

Comment: If you're just looking to stop the submit, try passing 'e' through your function and using e.preventDefault();  That should prevent the default events of the click (which include the submit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent enter key event. So form will not submit directly and user need to press save button to submit form.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```